# How do I tell if a win32 application uses the .NET runtime

Tags: .net, executable

How do I tell if an executable is a .NET application?

I prefer not to have to install Visual Studio. But if I have to I will. A commandline program is preferred.

Comment: Technically, it's either a .NET application OR a Win32 application.

Comment: Rather, every .NET application is a Win32 application that boostraps the .NET Runtime.

Comment: A .Net "executable" is more like a auto-execute zip file.  The executable contains your source code and a small Win32 program that launches the .Net compiler which then extracts the source code from the executable, compiles it, then runs it.  Its basically a fake executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PEVerify` will do that  :)

Answer (score 11):

An application is a .NET executable if it requires mscoree.dll to run. You can check for this using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), but in general any tool that gives you the list of required DLL's to run will do.

If you want to know if a running process is a .NET process, I can only recommend [Process Explorer](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). This tool will give you a lot of information about the process, including some .NET properties.

Comment: The website you reference has broken links

Comment: @ChristopherJSmith Indeed, but the website itself still works. I suggest you take it up with the website maintainer.

Answer (score 6):

Or simpler : use the Process Explorer. Free download [here](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessExplorer.zip)

Answer (score 6):

Process Explorer colors dotNet applications using yelow color by default. 
That should be enough :)

Answer (score 2):

Drop it into [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and it will be de-compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ILDasm.exe whitch is installed by default together with installing the .Net Framework SDK on your machine (look in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin) Just open ildasm.exe en drop de the assembly in it, if it's dissambled it's a .net, if you receive an error it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler yet:

1. Open the properties, look at the tab "Version", if under "Other information" you see a property called "Assembly version" then it is likely a .NET application.
2. Open the EXE or DLL with notepad or similar app and look for the text "mscorlib" (without the quotes). If you find it, it will most likely be a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

> "I prefer not to have to install
>   Visual Studio. But if I have to I
>   will. A commandline program is
>   preferred."

You don't have to install Visual Studio just to run a .NET application - just the .NET framework which you can download on it's own.

But, if you want to determine whether it's a .NET application, you can download and use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or use ILDasm, which comes with the .NET framework SDK.

Comment: ILDasm comes from the .NET Framework SDK, which is downloadable freely and doesn't require Visual Studio.