# How could we found one exe file is .Net exe or regular exe?

Tags: .net, file, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell if a win32 application uses the .NET runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751254/how-do-i-tell-if-a-win32-application-uses-the-net-runtime)

I have a file name, and I check this file exist in current directory, my problem is I want to know this file( the file is executable)  is .Net exe or regular exe.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or are you simply asking how to find out?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638883/how-does-windows-differentiate-between-a-regular-exe-and-a-net-exe

Comment: Difficult because the OS doesn't know.  The .exe contains code that launches the CLR and passes the assembly to the CLR for execution. You could try finding some signature of that code and looking for it in the file, or searching the file for signatures related to the metadata.

Comment: You want to serach for EXE files?

Comment: in my problem, depend on the kind of these exe I must do some routin

Comment: @MRM - A programming question requires code.  I remove the VB.NET and C# since this question is about the .NET Framework.

Comment: For a programmatic approach; read the .exe header info;

more info on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65122

Comment: every one, thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) method. This will throw an exception if the assembly is not a .NET assembly, or relies on a newer version of the framework. As long as you are using the latest version of the framework, the following sample will only return false when the path is not a .NET assembly.

```
public bool IsNetAssembly (string path)
{
    try
    {
         Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
         return true;
    }
    catch (BadImageFormatException e)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("This is either not a .NET assembly, or is " + 
                           "later than the current .NET framework");
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct an [`AssemblyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx), and call [`Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y.aspx) in a try-catch block. If you do not get an exception, it's a .NET assembly. This is not bullet-proof, but may provide a reasonable way to get started.

Comment: Just for info. But if I use 32bit prog and try this method on a 64 bit assembly what happens?

Comment: @Steve [BIFE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx), of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
try
{
    MessageBox.Show(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\test\csharptestapp.exe").ImageRuntimeVersion);         //Valid, will return 4.0
    MessageBox.Show(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Windows\notepad.exe").ImageRuntimeVersion);            //Invalid, will throw BadImageFormatException
}
catch (BadImageFormatException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar question here:
[How do I tell if a win32 application uses the .NET runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751254/how-do-i-tell-if-a-win32-application-uses-the-net-runtime)

It says to use `PEVerify Tool` from Microsoft.